# custom error handler unable to throw error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

While using the custom error handle its doesnt works and default error handler throws error.....
Controllers file is:

```
exports.getproducts = CatchAsyncErrors(
    async (req, res) => {
        const ResultsPerPage = 12;
        const seachfilterapi = new SearchFilterAPI(PRODUCT.find(), req.query).search().filter().paginate(ResultsPerPage)
        const TotalProducts = await PRODUCT.countDocuments();
        const products = await seachfilterapi.query;
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            Count: products.length,
            TotalProducts: TotalProducts,
            products,
        })
    }
)
```

Error file is:

```
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorhandler");

module.exports = function ErrorsMiddleware(err, req, res, next){

    err.statuscode = err.statuscode || 500;
    err.message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';

    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "DEVELOPEMENT"){
        res.status(err.statuscode).json({
            success: false,
            error:err,
            message :err.message,
            stack : err.stack
        })
    }

    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "PRODUCTION"){
        let error = {...err}

        error.statuscode = err.statuscode,
        error.message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error'

        res.status(error.statuscode).json({
            success: false,
            message : error.message
        })
    }
}

class ErrorHandler extends Error {
    constructor(message, statuscode) {
        super(message);
        this.statuscode = statuscode;
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);

    }
}
```

while using the error handler the custom error handler doesnt work and default error handler throws error

Answer (score 0):

I think You should remove the ErrorHandler class from the controller file and keep it only in the error handling file.

```
// error handling middleware file
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  constructor(message, statuscode) {
    super(message);
    this.statuscode = statuscode;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

module.exports = function ErrorsMiddleware(err, req, res, next) {
  err.statuscode = err.statuscode || 500;
  err.message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEVELOPMENT') {
    res.status(err.statuscode).json({
      success: false,
      error: err,
      message: err.message,
      stack: err.stack,
    });
  }

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION') {
    let error = { ...err };

    error.statuscode = err.statuscode;
    error.message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';

    res.status(error.statuscode).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};

// controller file
exports.getproducts = CatchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const ResultsPerPage = 12;
  const seachfilterapi = new SearchFilterAPI(PRODUCT.find(), req.query)
    .search()
    .filter()
    .paginate(ResultsPerPage);
  const TotalProducts = await PRODUCT.countDocuments();
  const products = await seachfilterapi.query;
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    Count: products.length,
    TotalProducts: TotalProducts,
    products,
  });
});
```

Comment: Still Doesn't works